# Маршрутизация трафика на дополнительный канал

Tags: маршрутизация, маршрутизатор

Здравствуйте. Имеется:

```
роутер_adsl: 
192.168.1.1 
255.255.255.0
dhcp 192.168.1.100-200
wan_adsl 83.174.216.111
gateway 83.174.192.36

роутер_3g:
192.168.1.2
255.255.255.0
dhcp - false
3g - 10.11.12.10
```

нужно прописать маршруты для всех машин в сети так, чтобы на 3G отправлялся только e-mail трафик. Допускаю изменение в настройках каждого компа.

Comment: Если у вас клиентские машины под linux, то легко, маркируете нужный трафик iptables, заворачиваете в нужную таблицу маршрутизации ip rule. Если винды, то боюсь у вас проблемы ... Проще переделать прошивку на одном из роутеров на какой нибудь openWrt и там линксовыми средствами это разруливать.

Comment: как вариант могу поднять сервер с несколькими карточками на линукс, к тому же мне нужно как то организовать отслеживание трафика в сети, и его блокирование. у меня в восновном виндовс

Comment: Ну там все достаточно просто https://habrahabr.ru/post/108690/ особенно обратите внимание на раздел Использование маркировки пакетов iptables. надо будет промаркировать все порты используемые почтой